# How to work with filepond plugin, ajax and php, file name not detected on the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, filepond

I am trying to upload file to an xammp server. I'm unable to access the file it uploaded. I doubt on this link `server: 'http://localhost/'`, because when I change it to the name of PHP file that process data on the server side it works.

But also I added another field called username on the form, look below on the code, and I want to combine them on single submit event with Ajax, but I have no idea for this combination.

```
  //initialize file pond with jquery plugin
  $('#file').filepond({
    allowMultiple: false,
    server: 'http://localhost/'
  });
  //ajax

$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'send.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData(this),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
  }).done(function(data) {
    if (data.success == false) {
      if (data.errors.username) {
        $('#username').append('<span class="text-danger">' + data.errors.username + '</span>');
      }
      if (data.errors.file) {
        $('#file').append('<span class="text-danger">' + data.errors.file + '</span>');
      }
    }
  });
  
  e.preventDefault();
});

//my form field between form tag
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>

//php code validate file and name
$errors = [];
if(empty($_FILES['username'])) {
    $errors['username'] = 'Enter your name!';
}
//other validation goes here...
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $errors['file'] = 'upload file!';
}
//other validation goes here...
echo json_encode($errors);
```

**EDIT:**
I notice that the name attribute in the input type file is not available/removed by the plugin and the input ID is also overwritten every time i load the page,

```
//example the input look like where the id="filepond--browser-men6qus3m" change every time i load new file


<input class="filepond--browser" type="file" id="filepond--browser-men6qus3m" aria-controls="filepond--assistant-men6qus3m" aria-labelledby="filepond--drop-label-men6qus3m" accept="image/png">
```

Thus why i get undefine typoerror and the file not attached

Comment: please do not edit answers to reply. Just put a comment with the button below the answer

Comment: if you read the documentation [here](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server) you will see that server is a path relative to where you run the js script where the server api is located. http:// is used if the endpoint is on a different server. otherwise `./` is used for the same folder and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to send a FormData with Ajax request. The problem you've mentioned here is that you want to include the file which is attached using `FilePond` library. Here is my solution to append FilePond files to a FormData:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    pond = FilePond.create(
        document.querySelector('#file'), {
            allowMultiple: true,
            instantUpload: false,
            allowProcess: false
        });

    $("#upload_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData(this);
        // append files array into the form data
        pondFiles = pond.getFiles();
        for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++) {
            fd.append('file[]', pondFiles[i].file);
        }

        $.ajax({
                url: 'fileupload2.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: fd,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //    todo the logic
                    // remove the files from filepond, etc
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //    todo the logic
                }
            }
        );
    });
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-filepond/filepond.jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>

<form id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="filepond">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

And on your PHP side, you need can get the files like this:

```
$errors = [];

if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $errors['username'] = 'Enter your name!';
}

// check if file is set and uploaded.
if (!isset($_FILES['file']) || $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    $errors['file'] = 'upload file!';
} else {
    $filesNum = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    // Looping all files
    for ($i = 0; $i < $filesNum; $i++) {
        // same the file
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
    }
}

// Other validation goes here...
// Return the proper response to the client
// I'll leave this to you
```

And note that:

- I've disabled `instantUpload` and `allowProcess` on FilePond to prevent auto uploading and processing.
- Your PHP side needs more validation and also it should return proper response to the Ajax.

Comment: @ubongo I updated the answer, please let me know if it worked.

Comment: it works, on validation no the so called unidefined name on field, but the trouble, is when i click the button to submit data, it send only name no file sent, please look my ajax code, and when i ignore validation for name, and remove all ajax code, and replace the server url in filepond options to server: 'name of php script' it works why?

Comment: When I inspect the form data on console there is only field file with no value while the field name have the value

Comment: @ubongo Could you please try the updated answer.

Comment: @ubongo I guess the new problem is about your URL. I kept it as it was on your question.

Comment: Thanks, now it send the file as base64 encoded and other data

Comment: @ubongo YW, I've updated the answer to use blob instead of base64. I think this is a better way.

Comment: Thanks bro, you nailed it, my last question here but i'm so sorry, I want to remove file from the user after user click submit, Tried working with `.filepond--file-wrapper` by using `.d-none` bootstrap class by calling `$('.filepond--file-wrapper').addClass('d-none'); ` after success function, yes it hide but the drug drop label not showing as previous until user reload page, Any idea please?

Comment: @ubongo You can use `pond.removeFiles()` to remove them all.